# how to get a value from array in bash

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

In the below i am checking the exit status , if it is not zero(which is a failure) i am displaying it by echo statment

```
while read -r record
 reccount=$((reccount + 1 ))
/usr/bin/java -jar NSGalinaMail.jar "$email_text"  "$email_subject" "$contact_email" "billingdept@ups.com" $lang  $cny_cd $MY_WORK/"Notify_$2.pdf"
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            emailCountFailure[$reccount-1]="Failure: Email to $contact_email for $ref_nr"
            echo "$emailCountFailure"
        fi
        echo "record_count=$reccount" >> $MY_WORK/"raw_data_$2"
        echo "emailCountFailure=$emailCountFailure" >> $MY_WORK/"raw_data_$2"
done < fileName ## a file with 10 records##
```

what ia m expecting is at least a 0 value if there is no failure, but it displays blank

```
emailCountFailure=
```

any solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

at least you forgot `while ... ; do`.
Here is my version doing what you may expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

# proposed
set -e
set -u
# disable in production code
#set -v
# disable in production code
set -x

reccount=0
declare -a emailCountFailure
while read -r record; do
    reccount=$((reccount + 1 ))

    # do not exit on non-zero status
    set +e
    # execute something
    perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -E "say 1/$record" > /dev/null 2>&1
    # store exit code as `set` will exit, too
    _rc=$?
    # re-enable exit on non-zero status
    set -e

    idx=$[$reccount-1]
    if [ $_rc -eq 0 ]; then
        # I don't know if you need this
        emailCountFailure[$idx]=''
    else
        emailCountFailure[$idx]="Failure: division by $record"
        # do what you need
    fi
done < lines

echo "record_count=$reccount"
echo "emailCountFailure=$emailCountFailure"
```

The file `lines` contains just lines of numbers and chokes on 0.

Hope that helps.